# Not able to migrate for my custom user model

Tags: python, django

Hey guys I am having this problem with my django migrations when I am trying to create a custom user model for my website

So what is happening is when I run migrations it throws an error on me saying:-

ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'user.newuser', but app 'user' doesn't provide model 'newuser'.
The field user.UserInfo.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'user.newuser', but app 'user' doesn't provide model 'newuser'.

I tried my best to try and debug it but it nothing is working i also did follow a answer on stack overflow but that also did not work I have implemented everything that is needed so yea the rest is the rest, and here is my code along with the migrations file

models:-

```
class CustomAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, first_name, last_name, phone_number, email, password, 
**other_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('You must provie an email address'))

        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError(_('You must provide a first name'))

        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError(_('You must provide a last name'))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, 
phone_number=phone_number, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, phone_number, password, 
**other_fields):
        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True'))

        if other_fields.get('is_active') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must be assigned to is_active=True'))

        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True'))

        self.create_user(email, first_name, last_name, password, phone_number, 
**other_fields)

class NewUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, blank=True)
    confirm_password = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    pin_code = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=6, blank=True)
    region = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

Migrations:-

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('auth', '0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length'),
    ('user', '0015_delete_newuser'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='NewUser',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
            ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
            ('first_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, null=True)),
            ('last_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, null=True)),
            ('email', models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=200, null=True, unique=True)),
            ('password', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, null=True)),
            ('confirm_password', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, null=True)),
            ('phone_number', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=10, null=True)),
            ('address', models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)),
            ('pin_code', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=6, null=True)),
            ('region', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, null=True)),
            ('state', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, null=True)),
            ('start_date', models.DateField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
            ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
            ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
            ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.group', verbose_name='groups')),
            ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
        ],
        options={
            'abstract': False,
        },
    ),
]
```

settings:-

apps-

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'home.apps.HomeConfig',
'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
'user.apps.UserConfig',
'reservation.apps.ReservationConfig',
]
```

calling the new user model-

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.NewUser'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the user model mid-project is a difficult situation if you are trying to override the existing user model with a `NewUser`. [Reference](https:///) You will need to write a custom migration to do it to transfer all data from the current `User` table to the `NewUser` table, then drop the `User` table safely.

If that's not the case and you just started the project, feel free to drop your current database and `make migrations` again after changing the default user model in `settings.py` (you are doing that already). Also make sure all imports in other files are undated to use your `NewUser` model instead of the django default `User`.

Comment: Thank you bro it was of great help
But one last thing. can you show me how to write a custom migration to override an existing user model cause i have never done one
but i have tried to edit a migration

Comment: This article explains it really well: https://medium.com/quick-code/how-to-create-custom-migrations-in-django-610718f49ae2